# Distinguish /< from < in python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, backslash, findall

I have a pattern that findall the tags in this format, <.* :.*> .
From nested tags, I am taking only the child tag.
Here I need to distinguish the brackets(< and >) from '/<' and '/>'.
Is there any way that I can do this in the same pattern itself?

eg : input string

```
<testing this> any text </<this is not a tag>any text<this will fail/>>
```

output:

```
['<testing this>','</<this is not a tag>','<this will fail/>>']
```

Any suggestion please let me know.

Comment: It looks uncomfortably like you're trying to parse [X]HTML with regex. [Don't.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3001761) Use a parser, it's what they're for!

Comment: If you want to use RegEx, you should use a LookBehind.

Comment: what does `/<` mean? you sure it's not `</` or `\<`?

Comment: Use backticks \` to surround your code / unformatted snippets. Also, what is your original regex? `

Comment: I updated the input/output formatting (4 spaces).. What is the desired output though?

Comment: I used this pattern, `re.findall('\<[^\<.*\>]+\>', input_string)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this pattern:

```
(?<!/)<.*?(?<!/)>
```

The `(?<!/)` is a negative lookbehind that assures there is no slash directly to the left of each `<` or `>` without actually consuming the character.

[Check this pattern out on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/sQ5sE9/1)